# Let $x_n$ be a sequence. Prove that $x_n \rightarrow 0 $ iff $(x_n)^{2} \rightarrow 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, self-learning

Let $x_n$ be a sequence. Prove that $x_n \rightarrow 0 $ iff $ (x_n)^{2} \rightarrow 0 $

**Attempt**

Assume that $(x_n)^{2}$ converges to zero. So $| x_n|| x_n| \lt \epsilon'$ after some stage. Thus $| x_n|<\epsilon'/| x_n|$. Choose $\epsilon'$ to be $\epsilon | x_n|$. Is this an acceptable proof?

Comment: It is not an acceptable proof.  You can't have $\epsilon$ depend on $n$ like that.

Comment: How do you know that $x_n$ doesn't equal zero? Dividing by zero would be a big no-no to my mind.

Comment: Just show that if $|x_n^2-0|<\epsilon$ then $|x_n-0|<\epsilon$ as long as $x_n<1$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant why the condition x_n <  1?

Comment: @GregoryGrant: did you miss a square in the first $\epsilon$?

Comment: @PedroM. Yes...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not acceptable. You have to prove that, from some point on, $|x_n|<\varepsilon$. And $\varepsilon$ must be fixed, you're not allowed to “choose one”. You are allowed to choose the place from where the inequality $|x_n|<\varepsilon$ holds.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. We know that there exists $m$ such that, for $n>m$, $|x_n|^2<\varepsilon^2$, which implies $|x_n|<\varepsilon$.

The other direction is similar. Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Then there is $m$ such that, for $n>m$, $|x_n|<\sqrt{\varepsilon}$. Then, for $n>m$, $|x_n^2|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: How have you taken epsilon square here ,and how second last step implies last one

Comment: @K.Dutta If $a^2<b^2$, with $a\ge0$ and $b\ge0$, then $a<b$, because the square root is increasing on the interval $[0,\infty)$. Since I want to find $|x_n|<\varepsilon$, it's natural to start from $|x_n^2|<\varepsilon^2$.

Comment: But x_n is positive is not given in question

Comment: The statement says if and only if, so you should prove the other direction as well. (At least note that it should be proven)

Comment: @K.Dutta But $|x_n|\ge0$

Comment: @K.Dutta $\vert x^2 \vert \to 0$ means that for **any** $\epsilon > 0$ we find a $m \in \mathbb N$, such that $\vert x_n^2 \vert < \epsilon$ for $n \geq m$. So by taking $\epsilon^2$ we find a $m' \in \mathbb N$, such that $\vert x_n^2\vert < \epsilon^2$ for $n \geq m'$.

Comment: @wythagoras if $ x_n < \ sqrt epsilon$ ,doesn't squaring gives other part to be proved ?

Comment: You want $|x_n|$. Yes, correct, but it is an essential (though quite trivial) part of the proof, so I wanted to note.

Answer (score 1):

For the "if" part, we know that for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists a number $N(\epsilon)$ such that $|x_n|^2<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N$.

This means that for all $\epsilon>0$, $|x_n|<\epsilon$, whenever $n>M=N(\epsilon^2)$.

The same approach can be used to show the "only if part."

Answer (score 1):

No, what you have to do is show that given $\varepsilon$ for one, you can always find $\varepsilon'$ for the other and vice versa.

One direction is easy: suppose $x_n \to 0$. Then by the definition of convergence there is an $N$ so that $\lvert x_n \rvert <1$ for $n>N$. Then you have $x_n^2<\lvert x_n \rvert $, because the left-hand side is the right-hand side multiplied by a positive number less than one. Now suppose you have $\varepsilon>0$, and $\lvert x_n \rvert < \varepsilon $ for $n>N'$, say. Then $x_n^2 < \lvert x_n \rvert <\varepsilon$ by the above, and hence for every $n>N'$, $x_n^2 < \varepsilon$. Since this holds for any $\varepsilon>0$, we then have $x_n^2 \to 0$.

Other way: suppose $x_n^2 \to 0$. Then given $\varepsilon>0$, there is an $N''$ such that $x_n^2<\varepsilon$ for all $n>N''$. It follows, by taking square roots of the inequality, that
$$ -\sqrt{\varepsilon} < x_n < \sqrt{\varepsilon}, $$
or $\lvert x_n \rvert < \sqrt{\varepsilon} = \varepsilon'$, say. So we have that if $n>N''$, $\lvert x_n \rvert < \varepsilon' $, and for any such $\varepsilon'>0$, we can find a corresponding $N''$ so that $\lvert x_n \rvert < \varepsilon' $.

---

Alternative: show that $x_n^2$ is Cauchy iff $x_n$ is.
$$ \lvert x_n-x_m \rvert^2 < \lvert x_n^2-x_m^2 \rvert = \lvert (x_n+x_m)(x_n-x_m) \rvert < 2A \lvert x_n-x_m \rvert, $$
the first being the triangle inequality, the second because $(x_n)$ converges, and hence is bounded in absolute value by $A$, say.